# Grabbying text from various document formats in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ms-word

I'm new to Rails but am developing a web app that requires taking text from a large database of text files and displaying the text in html. The files are in .doc, .docx, .wps, and .pages, and are currently just sitting on a hardrive. There are a small enough number of files in .wps and .pages that I could convert these to .doc manually, but the question remains: how do I get to the text inside a .doc or .docx file so that I can save it into a sqlite database for later use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Yomu](https://github.com/Erol/yomu). It's a gem which acts as a wrapper for [Apache TIKA](http://tika.apache.org/) and it supports a variety of document formats which includes the following:

- Microsoft Office OLE 2 and Office Open XML Formats (.doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .pptx)
- OpenOffice.org OpenDocument Formats (.odt, .ods, .odp)
- Apple iWorks Formats
- Rich Text Format (.rtf)
- Portable Document Format (.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

It's a long roundabout way, but open office can convert files, and there are programmatic ways to do that:  http://railstech.com/2010/08/convert-open-office-document-to-another-open-office-format/

That may not be the best way yet, but maybe it will grease the wheels a bit.